# python - identify characters from numbers in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a small csv file, which has two columns:
Column A (which contains a list of random characters); Column B (which contains a list of random numbers).

Example csv:
blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo,   695108
pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia,   678425
apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf,   651374
...

I need to identify and extract just the characters from each line (ignoring the numbers), then print out the result.
Running the following code gives out both columns as output:

```
import csv
with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: You should include the example csv in the question, not link to it.

Comment: there are multiple similar questions on site.    Look around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. The `row` variable in your code will be a list that holds the elements of the rows in your file (so for your csv it will hold these elements one after another:

```
['blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo', '695108']
['pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia', '678425']
['apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf', '651374']
...
```

).

So if you just want to print the part with letters you have to alter your code like this:

```
import csv
with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]  # note the additional [0]!
```

This will only print the first element of this list (so following the example above this would print

```
blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo
pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia
apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf
...
```

)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  data = {}
  for row in reader:
    for header, value in row.items():
      try:
        data[header].append(value)
      except KeyError:
        data[header] = [value]

char_values = data['A']   # extract  Column A
int_values = data['B']    # extract  Column B
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, the following will work:

```
import csv
with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for each1 in row:
            if each1.isalpha():
                print each1
```

However, if there are mixed values in the data, you would need to go down one extra level, like so:

```
import csv
with open('small.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for each1 in row:
            item = ""
            for each2 in each1:
                if each2.isalpha():
                    item +=each2
            print item
```

Answer (score 0):

When u read the CSV you end up with multiple lists of one character and one number. Transpose all the lists (see *zip()* and *iterator.izip()* functions) and you'll end up with one list of all characters and one list of numbers. Just print the one you need.